# Android Unit Testing with Robotium

Tags: android, button, background-color, robotium

I make a Robotium Unit Test class.
In my app i have a button. This button changes background color depending on some results into the code.
My question is how can i assert the color of the button
I try something like this

```
assertEquals("", scStatusButton.getPaint().getColor());
```

But this displays me a negative big number.
How can i obtain something more apropriate?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you cannot get the Button backgroung color by using `getPaint()` method.
`getPaint().getColor()` will gives you the Text color of the button as int value.
It is pretty normal to having a negative vale as the answer for a code like;

```
int i = colorButton.getPaint().getColor();
```

Following is a way of assert the color of the button in unit testing with **Robotium**.

```
package com.anuja.bu.test;

import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.anuja.bu.BuHomeActivity;
import com.anuja.bu.R;
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

public class TestBuHomeActivity extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<BuHomeActivity> {

    private Solo solo;

    public TestBuHomeActivity() {
        super("com.anuja.bu", BuHomeActivity.class);        
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    public void testButtonColor(){

        int i = 1;

        Button colorTestButton = (Button) solo.getView(R.id.buHomeActivity_color_button);

        solo.clickOnButton("Color");

        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) colorTestButton.getBackground();
        int buttonColorValue = colorDrawable.getColor();

        if(i == 0){
            assertTrue(buttonColorValue == -65536); // Red
        }else{
            assertTrue(buttonColorValue == -16711936); // Green
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {

        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }
}
```

"**i**" is the thing that you have mentioned as "*depending on some results in the code*".